# Cannot update WSO2 scopes

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have created and published an API from the WSO2 publisher and it works fine. But if I try and edit the API like adding a new scope, then the changes are not getting updated. The scopes do not get updated in the WSO2 Store and are not available when calling the login API.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the carbon log? You can find the log in <WSO2AM>/repository/logs folder.

Comment: also what is the APIM version you are trying out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIM gateway has a resource cache which caches resource information (eg. scopes of resources). That cache is invalidated after every 15 mins by default. So, they may not be invalidated just after you modify them from publisher UI. So, you have to either wait 15 mins or restart the server.

All above is for gateway. If you don't see scopes in Store, there must be some issues occurred while creating scopes. You can check `wso2carbon.log` file for error logs.